# WPF Binding using a default value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I am using `Binding` to define three different colors to fill an `ellipse`

So to do that in my binding, I have used `converter` that contains an `Enum`

According to the `enum` returned, the fill color is changed

Some of my XAML :

```
<Ellipse Name="SignalStatus" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="29,35,14.2,68.2">
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <!--<Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/> -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!--SignalStatus "Unknown" -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStatus, Converter={StaticResource IntToSignalStatus} }" Value="Unknown">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Magenta"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!--SignalStatus "Permissive" -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStatus, Converter={StaticResource IntToSignalStatus} }" Value="Permissive">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!--SignalStatus "Restrictive" -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStatus, Converter={StaticResource IntToSignalStatus} }" Value="Restrictive">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
```

Converter:

```
public class IntToSignalStatus : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return SignalStatus.Unknown;

        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "0":
                return SignalStatus.Restrictive;

            case "1":

                return SignalStatus.Permissive;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return PlatformSkip.Unknown;

    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the specification docs they want the `Red color` to be set on the control by default.

How can I define a default  fill color ( the Red one) for my `ellipse` ?

PS: I'm beginner en WPF & C# Programming

Comment: Uncomment the setter? But if the enum only contains the Unknown, Pemissive and Restrictive options, there default value will only be applied if the binding fails for some reason.

Comment: I commented the setter because i'm not sure if it's correct. I thought that is the way to set a default value. but when i Run the project color displayed by default is Green which corresponds to `Permissive` Status in the converter

Comment: This is the expected behaviour if the SignalStatus returns Restrictive. When do you expect the "default" colour to be displayed? The DataTriggers override the default setter.

Comment: i expect the control displays the Red color (default) when i lunch my application.

Comment: It should unless the SignalStatus property returns either Permissive or Unknown. Then it should be Green or Magenta respectively. That's the behaviour you have implemented in your XAML. In other words, the colour can never be Red if the SignalStatus property is set to Permissive or Unknown.

Comment: The green color is displayed by default when I run the app. 
 So if i have understood !, the first value of  of the binding is returned. in my case the first one is set according to `Permissive` (redColor) which corresponds to 0 in the enum used in the converter.
Maybe that's why the `green` is shown !?

Comment: Yes, exactly, Your converter returns Permissive and that's why you see green.

Comment: Ok, I changed my converter, so i just put the `Restrictive` status in `case "0"`.

now i'm having the the `Red Color` displayed when i lunch the App. and that's what i expect

Comment: yes it is solved, thank you @mm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your converter should return `Restrictive` for the `Fill` property of the `Ellipse` to be set to `Red`. This will trigger your last `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SignalStatus, Converter={StaticResource IntToSignalStatus} }" Value="Restrictive">
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Only if the converter returns neither `Unknown`, `Permissive` nor `Restrictive`, your default (uncommented) setter will apply.

Answer (score 0):

XAML

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding MyColor}"></Ellipse>
```

MODEL

```
private string _myColor = "Red";

public string MyColor
{
    get { return _myColor; }
    set
    {
        _myColor = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("");
    }
}
```